# Как сделать чтобы бот реагировал на любое сообщение? Python pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

if message.text == message:

как сделать, что б бот реагировал на любое сообщение?

Answer (score 1):

Данный хэндлер будет реагировать на любое сообщение в чате. Если будут другие хэндлеры с командами, то этот должен находиться в самом низу

```
@bot.message_handler()
def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, человек') # Тут твоя функция
```